# Formatear fecha de un parametro

Tags: javascript

Tengo un parámetro dentro de una función llamado "date", que es un string con un formato de fecha como: "dia\mes\año"

Quiero darle un formato distinto, tipo: Septiembre 21, 2022.
por ejemplo: si mi función recibe 20/05/2022, quiero retornar Mayo 20, 2022

Si bien sé que tengo que tener un arreglo con todos los meses del año, sin embargo, no tengo idea de cómo plasmarlo en mi codigo de tal manera que de el resultado final.

Por el momento he intentado esto:

```
function randomDate (date) {  

const months = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", 
"Setiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

return months.toDateString(date)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el parámetro que recibe tu función es la fecha **`20/05/2022`** como string, podrías usar a **`/`** como separador utilizando el método [**`split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), en donde te devolverá un array con dichos elementos separados. Con este array tendrías que almacenarlo en variables para luego concatenarlos en tu **`return`**:

```
let array = date.split("/"); // usamos a "/" como separador => ["20", "05", "2022"].
```

---

Ahora para obtener el mes del arreglo, queremos obtener al elemento de **`months`** según el elemento de **`array`**, en este caso el elemento de **`array`** es **`05`**, de la cual se buscará a la posición **`05`** de **`months`** restando **`1`** porque las posiciones de un arreglo parten desde **`0`**:

```
let month = months[array[1]-1] // De "months" obtenemos a la posición "5", en donde "5" es la posición "1" de "array".
```

---

###### Código final:

```js
function randomDate(date) {
  const months = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio',
                  'Agosto','Setiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];

  let array = date.split("/"); // usamos a "/" como separador => ["20", "05", "2022"].
  let day = array[0]; // Del array, obtenemos el día => 20.
  let month = months[array[1]-1]; // De "months" obtenemos a la posición "5", en donde "5" es la posición "1" de "array".
  let year = array[2] // Del array, obtenemos el año => 2022.

  return month +" " + day + ", " + year; // Juntamos todos los resultados.
}

console.log(randomDate("20/05/2022"))
```

Comment: Holii cris, precisamente ya había llegado a la conclusion de que tenia que implementar un separador dentro de un array para así poder extraer y trabajar los datos, lo que si se me complico fue el momento de concatenar los elementos con el espacio y la coma, al tanto que vi la noti de tu respuesta, me sacaste la duda. Muchisimas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera muy fácil de mostrar la fecha en el orden que quieras.

Primero se agrega una constante que contiene la fecha actual:

```
const fecha = new Date();
```

Luego se agrega otra constante declarando los meses:

```
const meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Setiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
```

Luego así, para mostrar todo juntos, pero en el orden que queramos, indicamos la `fecha` seguido de los demás:

```
fecha.getDate() // Días

fecha.meses[fecha.getMonth()] // Meses

fecha.getFullYear() // Año
```

Y éste orden se puede cambiar como quieras, separados por el signo `+`:

```
fecha.getDate() + fecha.meses[fecha.getMonth()]
```

Este ejemplo final es lo que buscas?

```js
const fecha = new Date();

const meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Setiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

const dameFecha = meses[fecha.getMonth()] + ' ' + fecha.getDate() + ', ' + fecha.getFullYear();

document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = dameFecha
```

```css
.demo {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: el OP dice -> *si mi función recibe 20/05/2022, quiero retornar Mayo 20, 2022* -> de la cual no veo que esto se aplica aquí, más bien, los resultados son de la fecha actual, y no veo que el OP pida algo así.